# Javascript regular expression to test a keyword and a math expression in the same string

Tags: javascript, regex

So when it comes to regular expressions I javascript, I only know about 1%.

I am trying to write some code that detects math expressions (e.g 2 + 3).
Some time ago I found this on another question:

```
/(?:(?:^|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/I
```

This seems to work fine but I would only want this to work when there is a specific keyword in front.

So now I have something like this:

```js
var re = /(?:(?:^|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/i;
var str = "2 + 2";
console.log(str.match(re));
```

But I would like to have this:

```js
var keyword = "Some keyword ";
var str = `${keyword}2 + 2`;

//Regular expressio that should only work if "Some keyword" and math expression are there
var re = //the expression
//should match the string
console.log(str.match(re));




//But if the keiword is not there
var keyword = "";
var str = `${keyword}2 + 2`;

//Regular expressio that should only work if "Some keyword" and math expression are there
var re = //the expression
//should NOT match the string
console.log(str.match(re));
```

I have tried this but it doesn't really do what I expected:

```js
var one = /Some keyword /i;
var two = /(?:(?:^|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/i;



var one_or_two = new RegExp("(" + one.source + ")?(" + two.source + ")")

var str = "Some keyword 2 + 1";
alert(str.match(one_or_two))
```

I need all of this in a regular expression because I can't use str.match(re)

Is there a way to do this?

Anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to capture: the formula, the whole string, or nothing?

Comment: the whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor `two` regular expression contained an `^` assertion that prevented the match after a keyword.

Below is your last attempt, with this error corrected, named captures for the formula and the whole string added, and the question mark removed, so that "Some keyword" is now required. Also, I replaced `[eE]` with `e`, because of the `i` flag:

```js
var one = /Some keyword /i;
var two = /(?:(?:|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:e[+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/i;

var one_or_two = new RegExp("(?<whole>(" + one.source + ")(?<formula>" + two.source + "))")

var str = "Some keyword 2 + 1";
if (match = str.match(one_or_two)) {
    console.log(match.groups.formula); // Only the formula.
    console.log(match.groups.whole); // The whole string.
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only match if both are true? 
Because it returns the math expression even if "some keyword" is not in the string "str"
So if `var str = "2 + 2"` it will still return the expression when I match it but I only want it ro work when `var str = "Some keyword 2 + 2"`

Comment: To put it in context I am using it for speech recognition and I only want it to work when the user says the keyword before otherwise it would always trigger when the user says a number

Comment: See the updated answer. I added another group capture for the whole string (although, I don't think you really need it), and I remove the question mark after "Some keyword" making it obligatory.